# Google Map API v3: Remove Default start/end markers

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I am building a route using the GoogleMap API v3, I have custom markers in place, with a route going between the two. However, the routes and markers are considered separate from a programmatic standpoint. Everything is going well, except for: [image: this:] I'd like to remove the start A and end B markers. Any ideas and keep the custom markers? Thank you.

Comment: [`suppressMarkers:true`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#DirectionsRendererOptions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove by name or id
for example
you can push all marker when create

```
var markers = [];

var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    id : 1
  });

markers.push(marker1);

var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    id : 2
  });

markers.push(marker2);

for(i=0;i < markers.length;i++)
{

if(markers[i].id == 1)  //remove by id

markers[i].setMap(null);

}
```

or 
remove by index

```
markers[0].setMap(null);

markers[markers.length-1].setMap(null);
```

Comment: Both of these worked! Thank you guys so much!

Comment: you're welcome @mclayton